# Change survival plot template back to default

Tags: graphics, sas, survival-analysis

How to change the proc lifetest survival plot template back to default template?

Comment: More details please.  Specifically, which template store did you change the plot template in?  What does `ods path show;` return in the log?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you change a template, you change it in a particular template store.  If you run

```
ods path show;
```

That will write to the log which template store you are currently writing to ('UPDATE').  For me this returns:

> 1. WORK.TEMPLAT(UPDATE)
> 2. SASUSER.TEMPLAT(READ)
> 3. SASHELP.TMPLMST(READ)

The original template should be stored in SASHELP.TMPLMST.  If you overwrote it, it would be in the (UPDATE) store - in my case, WORK.TEMPLAT, although it's often in SASUSER.TEMPLAT.

Assuming your (UPDATE) is still the same as it was when you made the change, this should work:

```
proc template;
    delete Stat.Lifetest.Graphics.X;
run;
```

where X is the template you modified.  That will remove the 'customized' version and SAS will use the base version.

If your customized version is in SASUSER.TEMPLAT and that currently is READ but was once UPDATE, you can revert to that by running

```
ods path sasuser.templat(update) sashelp.tmplmst(read);
```

and then rerun the delete.

Comment: You can also reset your ODS path to default by simply submitting `ods path reset;`.